# Alternate row colors using a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

Here is my formatting rule which is applied to the Shifts sheet:

```
=MOD(MATCH(A2,'Pay Checks'!B:B,-1),2)=1
```

I want the Shifts sheet rows to alternate colors based on where the Punch-out matches the Pay Period in the Pay Checks sheet.

---

My attempt:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Shifts data:

```
Punch-in            Punch-out
12/2/2022 10:00 AM  12/2/2022 3:42 PM
12/5/2022 10:00 AM  12/5/2022 3:42 PM
12/6/2022 1:00 PM   12/6/2022 6:00 PM
12/7/2022 6:00 PM   12/7/2022 11:00 PM
12/8/2022 6:00 PM   12/8/2022 11:00 PM
12/13/2022 1:00 PM  12/13/2022 5:00 PM
12/14/2022 6:00 PM  12/14/2022 10:00 PM
12/18/2022 1:00 PM  12/18/2022 6:00 PM
12/21/2022 6:00 PM  12/21/2022 10:00 PM
1/4/2023 5:55 PM    1/4/2023 11:01 PM
1/5/2023 5:55 PM    1/5/2023 11:01 PM
1/10/2023 1:00 PM   1/10/2023 8:00 PM
1/15/2023 7:00 AM   1/15/2023 7:00 PM
1/17/2023 7:26 PM   1/17/2023 11:30 PM
1/18/2023 6:53 PM   1/18/2023 10:56 PM
1/19/2023 6:53 PM   1/19/2023 11:00 PM
2/5/2023 7:39 AM    2/5/2023 6:00 PM
2/11/2023 7:01 AM   2/11/2023 7:00 PM
```

Pay Checks data:

```
11/20/2022  12/3/2022 11:59:59 PM
12/4/2022   12/17/2022 11:59:59 PM
12/18/2022  12/31/2022 11:59:59 PM
1/1/2023    1/14/2023 11:59:59 PM
1/15/2023   1/28/2023 11:59:59 PM
1/29/2023   2/11/2023 11:59:59 PM
2/12/2023   2/25/2023 11:59:59 PM
2/26/2023   3/11/2023 11:59:59 PM
3/12/2023   3/25/2023 11:59:59 PM
3/26/2023   4/8/2023 11:59:59 PM
4/9/2023    4/22/2023 11:59:59 PM
4/23/2023   5/6/2023 11:59:59 PM
5/7/2023    5/20/2023 11:59:59 PM
5/21/2023   6/3/2023 11:59:59 PM
```

Comment: I think you could use Vlookup? Can you post the data as text, so we can copy/paste and attempt on our side?

Comment: @BruceWayne Added! To note: I did not attempt the Vlookup route because I need `match()` to give me a row number so that I can use it in `mod()`. My formula does work when applied to neighboring cells and properly gives me ones and zeros.

Comment: Why not convert to a table?

Comment: @pgSystemTester I'm not opposed, just not experienced enough to know how to approach it properly =)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus if you can get a 20.3k rating on SO, you are well beyond capable of figuring out what an Excel Table is. It wouldn't take more than 3-5 minutes. Watch a YouTube video at high speed, but basically keeps dynamic updated table. Hope you get what you need either way.

Comment: @pgSystemTester Wow. Thank you for that, HashTag Blessed

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(MOD(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW('Pay Checks'!$B$1:$B$100)/('Pay Checks'!$B$1:$B$100>=$B1),1),2)=1,FALSE)
```

It assumes that the Pay Checks list does not overshoot row 100. You might increase the range in case it's needed, but if the range is really big it will slow down your file.

Another possible solution that will not slow down your file even with a long Pay Checks list might be this one:

```
=IFERROR(MOD(IFERROR(MATCH($B1,'Pay Checks'!$B:$B,0),MATCH($B1,'Pay Checks'!$B:$B,1)+1),2)=1,FALSE)
```

In both cases the Pay Checks list has to be sorted from smallest to greatest Punch-Out.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it looks promising. Unfortunately I haven't had a chance to test it out yet.